# "Send" information from python app to other python app

Tags: python, signals

I have two python programs opened at the same time, and i would like that when i click one button in the first app, "send" some information to the second app.

Im trying to do by signals from PySide. I get how to send it with this little code:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtUiTools

class Foo(object):
    pass

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    mysignal = QtCore.Signal(int, str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.hlayout)
        self.b = QPushButton("Emit your signal!", self)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.b)
        self.b.clicked.connect(self.clickHandler)
        self.mysignal.connect(self.mySignalHandler)

    def clickHandler(self):
        self.mysignal.emit(123, "")

    def mySignalHandler(self, n):
        print n
        # print l

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

but i dont know how can i "recieve" this signal in the other python app.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about the apps communication ways, it's multi-thread or multi-process?